# What does (m/w) mean on German job adverts?

Tags: germany, job-hunting

I see a lot of German job adverts with "(m/w)" after the title:

> Web Developer (m/w)

Please could someone tell me what it means?

And also what "(m/f)" means in the same context.

Comment: a guess : man/women ?

Comment: männlich = male

weiblich = female

Comment: The same question popped up at the [Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/) a while ago, you may want to have a look [there](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/59664/why-are-places-specifying-m-f-in-the-job-title/59668#59668).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

*m* stands for *männlich* (= male), *w* stands for *weiblich* (= female).

Exceptions aside, job advertisements have to be formulated in a ‎gender-neutral way. There are three common ways how to do this:

- Use a term that is gender-neutral (the English term "Web Developer" would work, but the German translation "Webentwickler" not, as it could refer to male web developers only).
- Use the female and the male term (e.g., "Webentwickler / Webentwicklerin").
- Append "(m/w)" to a term that can be understood in a gender-specific way, which then denotes that it refers to both genders (e.g., "Webentwickler (m/w)").

I think "(m/f)" is the English translation for "(m/w)" (i.e., male/female).